# Changing Cell color to specific defined color

Tags: java, excel

I want to change the color of the cell to a color, that I define with java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
I used the code:

```
    Color sColor = new Color (200,0,0);
    XSSFColor userColor = new XSSFColor(sColor);    
     try {          
        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        Font font = wb.createFont();
        font.setColor(userColor.getIndexed());
        style.setFont(font);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException ex) {
            //Handle NumberFormat and NullPointer exceptions here    
       }
```

the color always remains black.

And the output of "System.out.print(userColor);" is: 
(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@2e1b928).
Actually it changes depending on the value that I type in "new Color (200,0,0);"

but the output of "System.out.print(userColor.getIndexed());" is always: (0).

any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `sColor` is defined by yourself,so it do not have related index

```
 font.setColor(userColor.getIndexed());//this line of code will not work
```

Check the API of **[Font](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html)**,there is no method for using custom color to set font,you can only use the default **[IndexedColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html)**.

So you need to change your design before the POI upgrades to support it

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering , do you have any method to define color to the background instead the font.
Actually my main goal is to differentiate the cells depending on their value.
"There is tool in excel called Heatmap, which do so, I want to invoke it ."
@lucumt